# Postfix: deliver mails without sender or recipient checks

Tags: postfix

We are trying to configure Postfix as a send-only SMTP (**to the real world**), without authentication or checks on the sender / recipient, and without delivering to a local unix user.

We achieved to disable the authentication and the sender checks, but we still get the following error about the recipient (ex: foo@bar.com) :

```
postfix/local[103]: ... to=<foo@bar.com>, relay=local, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: foo)
```

We tried the following solutions:

```
local_recipient_maps=
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
```

And even:

```
mydestination=bar.com,localhost
```

Did we miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a server at work that does pretty much exactly that.

In /etc/postfix/main.cf add/edit

```
mynetworks = cidr:/etc/postfix/mynetworks

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        [put any special rules here]
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject
```

Create /etc/postfix/mynetworks with eg:

```
127.0.0.1           OK

192.168.123.0/16    OK
```

Anyone who connects from one of the specified networks can send mail. Do not forget to restrict the networks that can relay messages.